# Ignore a specific function with cppcheck

Tags: cppcheck

I have a number of functions that contain inline assembler and cppcheck is (quite reasonably) showing errors in this code. Is there a way to tell cppcheck to ignore a specific function in it's checks? I can suppress individual errors, but then they would change as the code is updated.

```
// cppcheck-suppress ignoreThisFunction?
void test_func() {
    
    __asm
           ; enter   hl = void *src  // style:Variable 'hl' is assigned a value that is never used
           out (c),h // warning:Found suspicious operator ','
    __endasm;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I deal with tools like cppcheck or lint not properly understanding certain constructs is that I call them with a macro definition identifying the tool, and then using conditional compilation. This way I can hide arbitrary code or write something equivalent in proper C.

E.g. you run `cppcheck -DCPPCHECK=1 ...` in conjunction with

```
void test_func(void) {
#if CPPCHECK
    /* Hide asm from cppcheck. Somewhat mimick the asm semantics. */
    hl = *src; /* Or just leave it empty if that is not possible. */
#else
    __asm
    ; enter   hl = void *src
    out (c),h
    __endasm;
#endif
}
```